their faces' spots were ... (pronunciation of "faces'")

their faces' spots were ...

Do we have to pronunce the invisible 's' after the apostrophe? Or we don't pronounce it?

You never pronounce the Saxon Genitive (possessive) s after a noun pluralized by adding s. That's true even if the noun doesn't contain another s sound (such as the soft c in face).
So plural

the cats' owners
sounds the same as singular
the cat's owners
(if the single cat has more than one owner! :)


Some people enunciate the 's after a singular (proper) noun such as James. The rule there is you pronounce it if it's written (Saint James's Park), otherwise (Saint James' Park) don't pronounce it. If the context is entirely conversational, it's a personal stylistic choice.

I think there's a word missing after "doesn't".

Note also that you do pronounce it when you're adding to a non-plural that ends with "s". "Moses's" is pronounced like "Moseses".

@Barmar: No, that's wrong. No competent Anglophone ever enunciates three consecutive s's to indicate possession. Not even if we were talking about the two princesses' mother. And because we don't write the non-pronounced s, the possessive of Moses is just Moses'.

I know there's disagreement, but I learned that if a word ends in "s", but it's not a plural, you add "'s", not "'". https://www.niu.edu/writingtutorial/punctuation/apostrophe.shtml#:~:text=Apostrophes%20are%20used%20to%20form,%2C%20only%20'%20should%20be%20added.&text=university's%20women's%20students'-,Correct%3A,over%20the%20last%20several%20years.

@Barmar: Here's the evidence that hardly anyone writes the possessive /s/ in Jesus' hands, and they're hardly going to pronounce it if they don't write it. No doubt there will be more native speakers pronouncing it than writing it, simply because plenty of native speakers aren't all that "competent", and can't write. (But you gotta admit it does sound pretty dumb to even attempt it with possessive princesses's :)

Yeah, I think this is one of those rules that's regularly breached. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/445539/drop-possessive-apostrophe-for-noun-ending-in-s-double-s

@Barmar: I don't think it's "regularly breached" at all. My linked usage chart showed overwhelming preference for what I'm saying, and this ELU question has an exceptionally high vote tally for the same position. For learners to side with the woolly-thinking minority who enunciate Jesus's would be lamentable, and to even entertain thoughts of saying/writing their faces's spots would be insane.

...but I suppose I must accept that ignorance is on the rise.

Are we talking now about pronunciation or how the possessive is written (Jesus' versus Jesus's)?

The general rule is we don't write or pronounce an additional s if it's the Saxon Genitive appended to any word already ending in pluralising s. But the basic principle is almost always extended to include proper nouns ending with two consecutive s's, such as Jesus and Moses - plus it's increasingly being applied to proper nouns ending in a single s, such as St James' Park.

...the other (absolute) rule is If you pronounce it, you write it. If you don't pronounce it, don't write it.
